# Label Printer keeps pausing after each printed label

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printing, printer

Recently our company decided to replace the old computer hardware managing our industrial label printers and we were running in a strange but weird issue related to Office and how printing was changed since Office 2007 (Yes that's right). The problem is now solved although it's rather unnecessary. I wanted to post this since it may be related or similar on other label printers, even if it is very unlikely. Nether the less, someone else may find this very useful some day.

So here are some specs. The printer we had encountered the issue on, was a Zebra 220i4x 300dpi.It got the most recent firmware version and no matter what driver (driver installation software version) it had, it always printer one label, pause of 0,5 -2 seconds, one label, another pause.

We have found that this is the case with Office 2019, 2016, 2013 and 2010. To give you some insight on how this may be, Word 2007 processed the 3 copies of the same document as one document with 3 times the content. 2010 and above process the document three times if the normal settings are used and will always verify that the last page was printed before continuing the print. This causes the delay and is somewhat easy to solve. Please take this not as a fact but what we have concluded after trying many different settings. The solution can be found bellow / in the next post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we found is, make sure to change the printing setting in word from collated to uncollated. Due to this it will process each page individually and is in my eyes a good work around if you only have labels with one single page that pause for a short period after one label was printed.

Of course the better solution is to print it as a PDF but sometimes you have to adjust the label to fit the text and the special health & hazard symbols in the right slots. For this you can use something like adobe reader pro or maybe an open source PDF-Tool that allows you to make changes of which I haven't heard yet.